# DataTable Export to excel add new row before exporting

Tags: jquery, excel, datatables

I'm going straight to the point here. I'm trying to export excel file using datatbable... however what I want is to add new row before exporting the file. I'm really new to datatable so please bear with me..

here's what I've done so far.

on the `customize:function()` part I want to add new rows before the header...
the header is actually the parameter for generating the table..

sample:

`NAME:SampleName`

`Date From: 2016-05-01`

`Date To: 2016-05-31`

```
  /*dataTables*/
    var handleDataTableButtons = function() {
      if ($("#datatable-responsive-returns-report").length) {
        $("#datatable-responsive-returns-report").DataTable({
         "bSort": false,
          scrollX: true,
          iDisplayLength: 50,
          dom: "Bfrtip",
           buttons: [
              // 'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
              {
                extend:"copy",
                className:"btn-sm"
              },
              {
                extend:"excel",
                className:"btn-sm",
                text:"Export to Excel",
                customize:function(xlsx){
                  var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];
                  console.log(sheet);
                  /add new row
                },
                filename: ($(".universal_name option:selected").text() == "" ? $(".hid_universal_name").val() : $(".universal_name option:selected").text()) + " - " + $(".universal_title").val()+"("+$(".date_from").val()+" to "+$(".date_to").val()+")"
              }
          ],

        });
      }
    };

    TableManageButtons = function() {
      "use strict";
      return {
        init: function() {
          handleDataTableButtons();
        }
      };
    }();
```

thanks in advance...

Comment: Would it be possible to set a line hidden on normal view and set it to visible when exporting excel?